# Can my probation period be extended beyond the contractually agreed maximum?

Tags: employment-agreement

On my contract letter / offer letter, it says "Probation period would be for three months which can further be extended for further three month totaling 6 months".

But the employer wants to extend it beyond 6 months to a year.

Can it be extended?

Comment: Welcome on Workplace.SE! You are asking a legal question, which depends on your jurisdiction. Can you add where you are via a location tag?

Comment: Have you already startes the job and if yes, for how long? Have you asked the boss why?

Comment: This heavily needs a country tag and surrounding context to be answerable.

Comment: I would want to find out why you've not passed probation.

Answer (score 3):

This is a red flag of an unscrupulous employer. Consider if you want to remain in the position.

Any deviation from contract is a red flag and needs to be addressed. In this case it directly impacts your pay. You should refuse which implies you'll be job hunting and then at least you have some leverage.

Personally I'd just say no and see what happens.

Comment: The time I've seen this happen is when the employee is not performing as well as expected, but also it's not bad enough to want him gone. More of a yellow flag I would say, but serious still.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul I've seen it happen a couple of times because probation is less pay. But never seen probation extended twice, if they don't improve after one extension it makes sense to let them go as unsuitable.

Comment: If for op it's better to be fired than employed at the lower pay then sure, but generally I think people prefer to job hunt while employed, even if at extended probation. And firing is the possible outcome if OP refuses.

Comment: Firing is always a possible outcome, but lower pay is generally a bad idea. Ideally the OP job hunted after the first extension.

Comment: *because probation is less pay* is that always the case? In my experience, probation is not related to pay and is more about evaluating performance. Extending probation is not uncommon and is just seen as an indicator of "we're not sure if this is going to work out." Maybe it varies by region.

Comment: @dwizum I suppose so, my experience differs. Either way it is less pay or stalls your progress and puts you in a defensive position. I wouldn't put up with it unless I was desperate.

Answer (score 2):

> Can it be extended?

Of course it can, if both parties agree to that. Whether it can be extended unilaterally depends on your contract and local jurisdiction.

However, you are probably asking the wrong question. A better question would be "What's happening here and what should I do?". There are two possible scenarios

1. Your performance is borderline and the company still isn't sure whether they want you permanently
2. The company wants to squeeze the last little cent out of you and save as much money as possible.

In either case your action should be the same: start looking for a new job NOW. You are off to a bad start and the probability that you will be successful and happily employed there in 2-3 years from now is very low.

Comment: "Of course it can, if both parties agree to that." Not necessarily. Where I live, you cannot. You can call it "probation" all you want, but you will not get any of the legal advantages like shorter notice periods that comes with the legal construct of probation.